# How can I create a interface that receives a class, and not a instance of the class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, interface

I would like to create a interface which receives a actual class not a instance of the class.
something like this:

```
class checkIfGonextPage{
  localResult;
  next;
  constructor(localResult:string,next:string){
    this.localResult=localResult;
    this.next=next;
  }
}
 interface comp{
    CheckifCanGoNext: checkIfGonextPage;
}
let x:comp ={"CheckifCanGoNext":checkIfGonextPage}

let f = new x["CheckifCanGoNext"]("sss","")
console.log(f.localResult);
```

if I set CheckifCanGoNext to any it will work but I will loose the type.

Comment: You want `typeof checkIfGonextPage` or `new (localResult: string, next: string) => checkIfGonextPage`, and classes and interfaces are conventionally named with UpperCamelCase

Comment: perfect, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the [`typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) to get the type of a particular named value.  If you want to put the actual value named `CheckIfGonextPage`,  the class constructor, in the `CheckifCanGoNext` property of a `Comp`, then you can refer to that type as `typeof CheckIfGonextPage`:

```
interface Comp {
    CheckifCanGoNext: typeof CheckIfGonextPage;
}
let x: Comp = { "CheckifCanGoNext": CheckIfGonextPage }    
let f = new x["CheckifCanGoNext"]("sss", "")
```

You could also use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) to describe something that can be called with the `new` operator.  It looks like a [function call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) but with the word `new` before it:

```
interface Comp {
    CheckifCanGoNext: new (localResult: string, next: string) => CheckIfGonextPage
}
let x: Comp = { "CheckifCanGoNext": CheckIfGonextPage }

let f = new x["CheckifCanGoNext"]("sss", "");
```

Either way should work.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWBTYBrAkgMwOIHsB2iAHgC4AKYA5otAN4CwAUNM9CDsGCAEqIQCuIYgG5GLaARIimLYPgjEATn2DEcCgBRsO3XgOIAuaPIUBLPBQA04ogaOKzFAJS1RYlsXgmIAOi2ce-ILQALys7P66glJu7p4+EsQh1pKuzAC+jBkMeGAAtrwADmDA1AAqAJ4FiDgYLtLMZsSIChjF1LA4uQV1McwIyCgmGLBgeLgAcjaGxJXVtf2omLgJ5FTRLFliIIiJhIYdXUk00ABEC4PDoxM2J-tIi9j4NqvUWamsO9C1oQQA7tCEADaZ3uFxGYxwkxIJwAuuoTlAICcrCcTo53rI8BAcNtfDgKOoMHjtAE9I4pG9snlCm04HJFMpiABlEwUOrvRrNVolOmHej1NznIbg64kQx-aCacI6QK2YwOKwJQzy8zOYIAPjgoKWTxIL3emxY212+063VCxxBA2FV0hNzuAx1K0or0Y72NXySEqBVtQNohUOIsPhiORpzRGLkOMQeIJRL8MrJFKAA)